# Why is my flutter app not handling Spotify's API authorization after signing in?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, oauth-2.0, spotify

I'm making a flutter app using Spotify's API. I have a basic homepage that uses a button to launch a browser to login to Spotify. Here is my backend code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart';

class SpotifyAuth with ChangeNotifier {
  final String CLIENT_ID = "My client ID";
  final String ClIENT_SECRET = "My client secret";
  final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8000/callback";
  final String SCOPE = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
  // var state = 'your-state';
  late String _accessToken;
  late String _refreshToken;

  Uri createAuthenticationUri(){
    var query = [
      'response_type=code',
      'client_id=$CLIENT_ID',
      'scope=${Uri.encodeComponent(SCOPE)}',
      'redirect_uri=${Uri.encodeComponent(REDIRECT_URI)}',
    ];

    var queryString = query.join('&');
    var url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + queryString;
    var parsedUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    return parsedUrl;
  }

  Future<void> launchInBrowser() async {
    if (!await launchUrl(
      createAuthenticationUri(),
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    )){
      throw Exception('Could not launch Url');
    }
  }

  Future<void> launchAuth() async {
    await launchInBrowser();
    await initUniLinks();
  }

  Future<void> getAccessToken(String code) async {
    var body = {
      "grant_type": "authorization_code",
      "code": code,
      "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,
      "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
      "client_secret": ClIENT_SECRET
    };
    // Create a request header with the required information
    var header = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization":
          "Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode("$CLIENT_ID:$ClIENT_SECRET>"))}"
    };
    // Send the request to the Spotify token endpoint
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"),
        body: body,
        headers: header);

    // Check if the request was successful
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Parse the JSON response
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      // Get the access token from the response
      String accessToken = data["access_token"];

      // Store the access token for future use
      // ...
      _accessToken = accessToken;
    } else {
      print("Error");
    }
  }

  Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    // Get the latest initial link
    String? initialLink = await getInitialLink();

    // Check if the link contains a Spotify authorization code
    if (initialLink != null && initialLink.contains("code=")) {
      // Extract the code from the link
      String code = initialLink.split("code=")[1];

      // Use the code to get an access token from Spotify
      getAccessToken(code);
    }
    else{
      print("Nothing");
    }
  }
}
```

My redirect URI is set in the spotify dashboard.

My app widget calls `luanchAuth();`
and then it should wait for the authentication code with `initUniLinks()` but it seems like initUniLinks() executes immediately without waiting for the authentication. When I authenticate in Spotify, it throws a generic "can't connect to localhost" error page but the url includes the auth code that I need.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Admittedly I'm new to Oauth and app-api-connections in general but I thought this would work.

Answer (score 0):

REDIRECT URI is the problem here, You cannot have redirect URI with localhost it fails. either use ngrok and provide the mapped https url or host your callback url and provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom scheme for `redirect_uri`, something like this `my-app://token/callback`. See [App Settings](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/app-settings/) for Spotify rules.

Then configure the application for [Deep Linking](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) to receive the authentication response.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final String clientID = 'your-client-id';
  final String clientSecret = 'your-secret-client';
  final String redirectURI = 'spotify-demo://callback';
  final String scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';

  late String accessToken;
  late String refreshToken;

  Uri get createAuthenticationUri {
    var query = [
      'response_type=code',
      'client_id=$clientID',
      'scope=${Uri.encodeComponent(scope)}',
      'redirect_uri=${Uri.encodeComponent(redirectURI)}',
    ];

    var queryString = query.join('&');
    var url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?$queryString';
    var parsedUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    return parsedUrl;
  }

  Future<void> launchInBrowser() async {
    if (!await launchUrl(
      createAuthenticationUri,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    )) {
      throw Exception('Could not launch Url');
    }
  }

  Future<void> getAccessToken(String code) async {
    var body = {
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': redirectURI,
      'client_id': clientID,
      'client_secret': clientSecret
    };
    // Create a request header with the required information
    var header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$clientID:$clientSecret'))}'
    };
    // Send the request to the Spotify token endpoint
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'), body: body, headers: header);

    log('check status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    log('check body: ${response.body}');

    // Check if the request was successful
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Parse the JSON response
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      // Get the access token from the response
      accessToken = data['access_token'];
      refreshToken = data['refresh_token'];

      // Store the access token for future use
      // ...
      log('access token: $accessToken');
      log('refresh token: $refreshToken');
    } else {
      log('Something went wrong');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    handleLinks();
  }

  void handleLinks() {
    uriLinkStream.listen((event) {
      log('message handleLinks event happened: ${event?.query}');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Spotify Web API'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await launchInBrowser();
          },
          child: const Text('Get Token'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, add uniLink configuration in the 'AndroidManifest.xml'

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="spotify-demo"
                android:host="callback" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Please check the above code, I hope this will help you.